# Making Caps to the first letter automatically

Tags: javascript

I want to make the first letter in a text box to be capital but i have no idea on how i can apply it.  e.g sitholimela ----> Sitholimela

I want to apply this to a text box.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try this. It works.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Capitalizing first letter in a textbox</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function capitalize(textboxid, str) {
      // string with alteast one character
      if (str && str.length >= 1)
      {       
          var firstChar = str.charAt(0);
          var remainingStr = str.slice(1);
          str = firstChar.toUpperCase() + remainingStr;
      }
      document.getElementById(textboxid).value = str;
  }
  </script>
 <body>
  <form name="myform" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="mytextbox" onkeyup="javascript:capitalize(this.id, this.value);">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't need `javascript:` in the keyup event, only in `href` of `a` where it needs to be defined as execution code rather than address.

Comment: Better to keep keyup listener definition with other javascript, and keep HTML clean - makes it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 9):

### CSS

```
input[type=text] {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

This will make the text *appear* in this way.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/csC8K/

Comment: Just noting that this will do it to each word in the field, e.g. `foo bar` becomes `Foo Bar` and that it does not change the _value_, just how it is displayed.

Comment: It just shows that it is capitalized but it is not capitalized actually if you fetch the text.

Answer (score 7):

To do this in *JavaScript*, get the node, and replace it's *value* with your transformation

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('myTextboxId');

textbox.value = textbox.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + textbox.value.slice(1);
```

MDN pages

- [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)
- [`String.prototype.charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)
- [`String.prototype.toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)
- [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Answer (score 4):

### Working demo...

http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/mzXLc/1/

### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="targetBox">
```

### Javascript

```
var capitalize = function(e){
    // if the first letter is lowercase a-z
    // ** don't run the replace unless required, to permit selecting of text **
    if(this.value.match(/^[a-z]/)){
        // replace the first letter
        this.value = this.value.replace(/^./,function(letter){
            // with the uppercase version
            return letter.toUpperCase();
        });
    }
}

// listen to key up in case of typeing, or pasting via keyboard
// listen to mouseup in case of pasting via mouse
// prefer `up` events as the action is complete at that point
document.getElementById('targetBox').addEventListener('keyup', capitalize);
document.getElementById('targetBox').addEventListener('mouseup', capitalize);
```

Comment: like this version because copy paste still allows lowercase characters. But didn't like the behavior when I have a lowercase text. As soon as I click in the textbox the lowercase text changes.

If I leave out the mouseup event I have with lowercase text the problem that marking the text and replacing it the old text stays and the new text gets added to the end.